# Display div over everything

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

I'm struggling to display a div on top of everything else.

I've followed other post on SO which say to use z-index and position: absolute.

Here is a screenshot to describe what I mean.

[image]

Here are the css attributes on the classes:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  .cd-single-point .cd-more-info {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 1em;
    overflow-y: visible;
    z-index: 10;
    line-height: 1.4;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  }
}
```

If anyone is able to help me I'd really appreciate it.

The link can be found here https://what-is-wrong-with-this-css.herokuapp.com/.

Thanks

Comment: The link is here by the way.https://what-is-wrong-with-this-css.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issue with overflow in the class `.cd-image-wrapper`, you need to make it visible like this :

```
.cd-image-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    overflow: visible;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Comment: So quick! and what a boss! Thanks so much! Been looking for this for so long!

Answer (score 0):

Can you try and increase the `z-index: 999;`

Comment: Even with 1000 and !important, it's the same :/

Comment: Yep sure, doing now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try to increase the z-index to 9999
2. Try to use !important (maybe something is overriding it)
3. Try to decrease the z-index of the overlaping element (again try with !important)
4. Try to change something obvious in your media query to make sure that it is currently executed, for example change the background color

Note: this is just to experiment and find the cause of your issue, using "!important" is not recommended